# What code use for change id inventoryitem

Tags: acumatica

I would like to use this process, but I don't know with which code to use it ?
I want to change ID PRODUCTV1 to PRODUCTV2.

[image]

I find this function

```
public void ChangeCDInventoryItem(PXCache cache, string oldCD, string newCD, string type)
{
System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary keys =
new System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
{
typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD).Name, oldCD
},
{
typeof(InventoryItem.itemType).Name, type
}
};
System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary vals =
new System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
{
typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD).Name, newCD
},
{
typeof(InventoryItem.itemType).Name, type
}
};
cache.Update(keys, vals);
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the PRODUCTV2 as the value in that popup to change the PRODUCTV1 to PRODUCTV2

Comment: Samvel, thans for your answer, I find this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much simpler, if you need a basic change ID added. Here is code that works on the LocationMaint screen:

```
public class LocationMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<LocationMaint>
{
    public PXChangeID<Location, Location.locationCD> ChangeID;
}
```